# Создание абстрактного класса

Tags: python-3.x, ооп

Как в третьем питоне можно создать абстрактный класс, не используя модуль abc?

Answer (score 2):

Мне не до конца ясно, что Вы хотите делать с помощью абстрактного класса и какой функционал от него требуется. Если считать, что нам нужен виртуальный метод (а-дя c++), то можно использовать, например, исключения:

```
class A:
    def method1(self):
        raise NotImplementation('abstract class')

class B(A):
    def method1(self):
        print('method1')

b = B()
b.method1()
```

Но, по опыту, лучше использовать композицию следующего вида:

```
class A:
    method1(self):
        print('method1')

class B():
    def __init__(self, base_class):
        self.base_class = base_class


b = B(A())
b.base_class.method1()
```

Я не знаю приложений, в которых наследование бы давало выигрыш.

В последнем случае Вам будет много удобнее осуществлять тестирование, поскольку функционал класса `A()`, Вы всегда сможете представить как `mock`-объект. Тогда Вы можете протестировать класс `B()` отдельно и класс `A()` -- отдельно.

В данном случае пример, разумеется, искусственный, поскольку у класса `B()` нет ни одного метода. Так делать не стоит: если у класса нет ни одного метода, то его лучше редуцировать и не добавлять архитектурный шум.

Comment: Ничего не хочу делать. Вопрос чисто для ознакомления. :)

Comment: @Antoxer Вы хотите узнать, какие есть варианты?

Comment: Да, на работе сдаю теорию, попросили рассказать.

Comment: `Я не знаю приложений, в которых наследование бы давало выигрыш.` у меня есть хороший пример -- BaseServer https://github.com/gil9red/botanist/blob/6b6c5b09a96b2634496f63992efb557fa5258724/commands/base_server.py#L49 и его наследники https://github.com/gil9red/botanist/search?q=BaseServer&unscoped_q=BaseServer :)

Comment: @gil9red вопрос вкуса. Я знаю два подхода: dependency injection и наследование. Первый -- более устойчив к тестированию (удобнее), второй -- меньше копипасты. А ссылки Ваши не работают. Я писал этот ответ полгода назад и раньше мне так казалось. В большинстве случаев это так.

Comment: @hedgehogues, дело вкуса :) Ссылки рабочие, проверьте, что у вас хост github.com доступен. Насчет даты, не обратил на это внимания :)

Comment: @gil9red Доступен. Зайти не могу. 404

Comment: @hedgehogues, тьфу, он был приватный. Был. Сейчас в этом недобности :)

Comment: @gil9red можно в кратце, какой смысл в этом там?

Comment: @hedgehogues, идея была поиграться с ботом вк, у которого есть команды, но потом команд стало больше и мультипоточности стало мало и тогда каждая команда стала сервером, а т.к. копирование повторяющегося кода не радовало переписал сервера как классы, в которых различие в основном: имя, guid, команды-реакции, функция-обработчик команды. Все остальное -- общий код обработки запроса, подготовки ответа, запуска сервера --, есть у одного класса -- базового

Comment: Эту же задачу можно решить с помощью dependency injection. Принцип тот же. Только вместо наследования, Вы передаёте в качестве аргумента конструктору Ваш базовый класс и делаете его членом класса.